# SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:16) ('<') in my react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a react front-end for my node back-end. Currently, the front-end does not make requests to the server, but is just like a shell. It gives me this error, only from one file I have compared to the others. This is the code to the error-provoking file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom, {render} from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


export default class Access extends Component {
    render() {
        try {
            return (
                <div className="App"> //Error on this line
                    <div className={'container'}>
                        <div id={'add'}>
                            <h3>ADD</h3>
                            <input placeholder={'Name of task'}/> <p> or <br/></p>
                            <input placeholder={'ID of task'}/><p>*</p>
                            <p>*: Please only enter ONE of the above options</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id={'delete'}>
                        <h3>DELETE</h3>
                        <input placeholder={'Name of task'}/> <p> or <br/></p>
                        <input placeholder={'ID of task'}/><p>*</p> <p> Please confirm your choice by typing the
                        task's
                        name in the following input box.</p>
                        <input placeholder={'Name of task'}/>
                        <p>*: Please only enter ONE of the above options</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id={'Query'}>
                        <h3>By Task</h3>
                        <input placeholder={'Task'}/>
                        <h3>By Status</h3>
                        <input placeholder={'Task'}/>
                        <h3>My List</h3>
                        <input placeholder={'Username'}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }catch (err){
            throw(err);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\manan\Downloads\TodoApp\Frontend--React\src\FullFunctions.js: 
Unexpected token (11:16)

   9 |         try {
  10 |             return (
> 11 |                 <div className="App">
     |                 ^
  12 |                     <div className={'container'}>
  13 |                         <div id={'add'}>
  14 |                             <h3>ADD</h3>
```

Comment: This is valid JSX, so the question is probably about your bundler/transpiler of choice and its configuration.

Comment: Will it appear if you move the return outside the try-catch block?

Comment: Try renaming the file to `.jsx` and see if that helps.

Comment: RE:mbojko,
yes, it still gives an error if it is out of the try-catch block

Comment: Looks like you have an extra closing `</div>` to me.

Comment: Please close return element with semicolon.

Comment: In my Atom (using lint) I don't get any error for this line. I suggest that you try to remove inner <div></div> blocks and try to see if you get an error for a minimal number of lines.